# Caffe linking error, but ldd gives no error

Tags: ubuntu, linker, caffe, odroid

I am building caffe on an Odroid with Ubuntu 16.04 but I get a linking error:

```
[ 77%] Linking CXX executable compute_image_mean
CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/compute_image_mean.cpp.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<int, int>(int const&, int const&, char const*)':
compute_image_mean.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIiiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x28): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/compute_image_mean.cpp.o: In function `std::string* google::MakeCheckOpString<unsigned int, int>(unsigned int const&, int const&, char const*)':
compute_image_mean.cpp:(.text._ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIjiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc[_ZN6google17MakeCheckOpStringIjiEEPSsRKT_RKT0_PKc]+0x28): undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/compute_image_mean.cpp.o: In function `main':
compute_image_mean.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe6): undefined reference to `google::SetUsageMessage(std::string const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `leveldb::Status::ToString() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/build.make:130: recipe for target 'tools/compute_image_mean' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/compute_image_mean] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:467: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the output of `sudo ld lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0`:

```
sudo ld lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0 
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000101ec
lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `google::base::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString()'
lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)'
lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `cv::imencode(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `leveldb::Status::ToString() const'
```

According to `ldd lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0`, all the required libraries have been found. How can I identify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I stumbled across it in search of my own solution, I thought I'd mention what I discovered.  The error

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 000101ec
```

is almost definitely because you did not give `ld` any of the object files for the C runtime.  I am building on ARM (Raspberry Pi Zero, 32-bit Linux), so my copy of `ld` needs at least the following to link:

```
ld \
-dynamic-linker=/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 \
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10/crtbegin.o \
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/10/crtend.o \
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o \
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o \
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o \
<your other arguments>
```

It's also worth noting that you probably do not need to run the linker with `sudo`, since there is nothing privileged about linking programs, and the permissions resulting from having run as the superuser may cause you problems.

By the way, in case you are curious, you can actually find out where `_start` is really located by inspecting your object file using `objdump`.

```
$ objdump -D <your file> 2>&1 | grep _start
```

In my case, `_start` was missing altogether.  This was the clue I needed to realize that I was missing parts of the C runtime, since `_start` is the C runtime procedure that is executed before `main` is called.